# Dynamically enable or disable context menu items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform with multiple `PictureBox` controls on it. I have a context menu which is attached to all of these `PictureBox` controls. I have 3 submitems (menus) in the context menu which should be displayed in right click on any of the `PictureBox` instances and that works fine.

Now, before the context menu pop ups, I need to check the properties of `PictureBox` where it is clicked to enable or disable certain sub menus.

```
 private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I see this event, but the `sender` object is a reference of `ContextMenu`. I need the `PictureBox` parameter to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this but you might want to look at the [`SourceControl` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.sourcecontrol.aspx) of the `ContextMenu` (`sender`).

It should have a reference to the actual control the `ContextMenu` is being displayed for.

The MSDN page I linked to also has a sample that I think will be helpful. They are listening to the [`Popup` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.popup.aspx) though, but it should be the same.

Comment: thanks it works, I tried contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl in the same event it works